# Authentication to Azure Storage Account and Azure Service Bus using managed identity takes longer than using connection string

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity, azure-storage-account

I have a simple Azure function that got triggered on Service Bus Queue, downloads data from Storage Account, performs some simple logic and sends message to another Service Bus Queue.
Function was using connection strings (Shared Access Key) to authenticate.
To follow best practices and recommendations I changed the authentication method to be managed identity.
After this change, I noticed a significant decrease in performance = > download data from storage account and send message to queue takes 2.5 times longer.

As an example I created two simple functions. Both got triggered from service bus queue and download content from blob, the only difference is authentication method. Runtime of the first one is significantly less that second one.

```
 [FunctionName("TestFuncWithConnString")]
    public async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("testconstring", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
        ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
    {


        var storageConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("StorageConnectionString");
        var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(storageConnectionString, "containerName");   
        var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("XXX");
        var blobMessage = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();

        await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
    }


    [FunctionName("TestFuncWithManagedIdentity")]
    public async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("testmanagedidentity ", Connection = "SBNamespaceFQName")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
        ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
    {

        var storageConnectionString = new Uri($"https://{StorageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/");

        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(storageConnectionString, new DefaultAzureCredential());
        var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("containerName");
        var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("XXX");
        var blobMessage = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();

        await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
    }
```

Does someone have any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: Are you noticing the slowness for every request or just the first request? Please edit your question and include the code as well.

Comment: It happens not only for first request.

Comment: Please share your Function’s code.

Comment: We run some perf tests and got the avg_duration different for the same function with only difference in authentication  - managed Identity vs connection string authentication. Added to my question snapshot. To share function Code is not straight forward and requires some refactor. If there is no other way to figure it out will try to do it

Comment: I agree with Guarav that we'll need to see your code to help further.  How you're creating and managing the clients will be a large part of your performance characteristics.  Generally speaking, it is expected that managed identity authorization takes longer than a connection string, as both the client and service have to coordinate with AAD, where a connection string is validated entirely by Service Bus itself.

Comment: I created as example two functions, you can se details in the question. I agree that it might take longer because of AAD coordination, but 2.5-3 times longer is expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is expected that managed identity authorization takes longer than a connection string, as both the client and service have to coordinate with AAD, where a connection string is validated entirely by Storage itself.

Because you are creating your `BlobServiceClient` and `DefaultAzureCredential` on each invocation of the function, you're paying the cost to acquire the token and authorize on each call.  Azure SDK guidance encourages treating clients as singletons.  *(see: [Lifetime management for Azure SDK .NET clients](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/lifetime-management-and-thread-safety-guarantees-of-azure-sdk-net-clients/))*  Doing so would reduce the number of times that you need to authenticate and authorize, avoiding the need to pay that cost so frequently.

The recommended approach would be to use [Dependency injection for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) with the [AddBlobServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.azure.blobclientbuilderextensions.addblobserviceclient?view=azure-dotnet) extension defined by the Azure Blob Storage package.  Alternately, you could create a static instance of the `BlobServiceClient` as part of your function class - though you are likely to see that be less efficient over time.

Comment: Example above is just for demo. I agree that connection should be reused. I just wanted to understand if it is acceptable that authentication via managed identity takes 3 times longer. Thank you for confirming that this delay is expected.